# Java +Vaadin +Spring Security

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security, vaadin

I have problem with  UserDetailsServiceImpl()

> org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
>   creating bean with name 'securityConfig': Injection of autowired
>   dependencies failed;  The constructor UserDetailsServiceImpl() is
>   undefined

```
@Bean
public UserDetailsService userDetailsService(){
    return new UserDetailsServiceImpl();
}
```

---

```
@Service
@NoArgsConstructor(force = true)
public class UserDetailsServiceImpl implements UserDetailsService {

private final UserService userService;

@Autowired
public UserDetailsServiceImpl(UserService userService) {
    this.userService = userService;
}
```

Application failed to start((

Comment: it is a maven...

Comment: What maven command do use to run the project?

Comment: you  can see my project https://drive.google.com/file/d/17VQX490sQ4n5K8s94pCTFDAookQh0_hS/view?usp=sharing

Comment: I see your project but it doesn't answer the question. How do you run it?

Comment: application.java.....run as spring boot app

Comment: Thanks. I don't know which IDE you use to run the project and how it runs it, but for maven, a spring boot application should be properly run with this command line command `mvn sprint-boot:run`. At my side the application starts sucessfully. Please, try and let me know if it works. I'll post an answer explaining why it's required.

Comment: I use Eclipse, i cant start because " The constructor UserDetailsServiceImpl() is undefined"...but now i fixed my project below answer...

Comment: Did you try the command I suggested?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I saw your project and review something about that.Here you want to implement both User with `CustomUser` and `UserDetailsService` with custom userDetailsService.

1) Your `UserDetailsServiceImpl` class implements `UserDetailsService`. Inject your `UserService` with `Autowired` annotation. Remove this constructor or just comment it.

```
@Autowired
private UserService userService;

/*public UserDetailsServiceImpl(UserService userService) {
    this.userService = userService;
}*/
```

2) Annotate your interface `UserService` with `@Service` and it implementation class `UserServiceImpl` with `@Repository` as they are spring component.

3)Remove this Bean from `AppConfig` Class.

```
@Bean
public UserDetailsService userDetailsService(){
     return new UserDetailsServiceImpl();
}
```

4) As you create your custom `UserDetailsService` named `UserDetailsServiceImpl` so you need to introduce your custom implementation to `AuthenticationManagerBuilder`. To do this inject your custom class in `SecurityConfig` with `@Autowired` annotation.

```
@Autowired
private UserDetailsServiceImpl userDetailsService;
```

5) Yes, you are in last phase. set this userDetailsService to authentication manager by setting

```
@Autowired
public void registerGlobalAuthentication(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
    auth.userDetailsService(userDetailsService).passwordEncoder(getShaPasswordEncoder());
}
```

So you are almost done. Since you used `Spring-boot`, so it embedded with tomcat server (a servlet container). Go to your `pom.xml` and find packaging tag ( generally places at first )and change it to

```
<packaging>jar</packaging>
```

Now clean and build your project (In my case I used netbeans to clean and build, you can use maven command). After successfully build, you found a `/target` folder. Go to the folder and open terminal, run the jar with `java -jar music-review-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar`.

Your updated project can be found [here](https://drive.google.com/open?id=12FvvJOYQpU-IVMicXT5zZtTIJh_7GKKz).

Answer (score 0):

Create a interface named UserDetailsService;

```
public interface UserDetailsService{
    public void someMethod();
}
```

Implement the interface as follows

```
@Service
public class UserDetailsServiceImpl implements UserDetailsService {
    @Autowired
    UserDetailsService userDetailsService;

    @Override
    public void someMethod() throws Exception {
        //your implementation
    }
}
```